# CXF RAPI call - ApplicationListener

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I'm using the CXF-RS framework with Spring and Tomcat to build out a RAPI. I wanted to invoke some of these RAPI calls once all the beans are initialized, so I created a ContextRefreshedEvent ApplicationListener. However, no matter how long I wait, I always receive a SocketTimeoutException when trying to invoke the RAPI. It seems to be the case that the CXF servlet only boots up after the Spring ApplicationListeners, but is there a way for the opposite to occur? If ApplicationListeners are not the way to go, are there any other options?

Using Spring 3.2.10, CXF 2.4.2, Tomcat7

Thanks much!

Comment: Please, add the traces and the cxf and spring config

Comment: I realized my problem! It has nothing to do with Spring or CXF, but the fact that the webapp I was depending to startup was depending on the webapp I was creating. One had to give, and mine timed out first.